# Waffle not working on nginx - error “The token supplied to the function is invalid”

Tags: nginx, tomcat, spring-security, https, waffle

My application runs on tomcat (http) and I use nginx (https) for load balancing. When I authenticate window with waffle using http then everything works fine, but if I run waffle using nginx (https) I get the error “The token supplied to the function is invalid”

Please note that I run nginx using docker and here is the configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen              443                 ssl;
    server_name      localtest.product.local;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass          http://host.docker.internal:4200/;
        proxy_redirect      default;
        #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location /apc/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass          http://host.docker.internal:8081/apc/;
        proxy_redirect      off;
    }
    location /amb/ {
        proxy_pass          http://host.docker.internal:4200/amb/;
        proxy_redirect      default;
    }
}
```

is there any conflict between waffle and nginx? How to solve this.